# JQuery parents().eq(2) and .parent().parent() not behaving?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```
function showNotification(title, message) {
    var newNotification = $('<div></div>');
    var newNotificationHeader = $('<div>' + title + '</div>');
    var newNotificationCloser = $('<div></div>');
    newNotificationCloser.click(function(){
        closeNotification($(this).closest('notification'));
    });
    var newNotificationMessage = $('<div>' + message + '</div>');

    newNotification.attr('class', 'notification');
    newNotification.css('opacity', 0);
    newNotificationHeader.attr('class', 'notificationHeader');
    newNotificationCloser.attr('class', 'notificationCloser');


    newNotificationMessage.attr('class', 'notificationMessage');

    newNotificationHeader.append(newNotificationCloser);
    newNotification.append(newNotificationHeader);
    newNotification.append(newNotificationMessage);

    $('body').append(newNotification);
    newNotification.animate({left: '10px', opacity:1}, 400).delay(15000).animate({top: '61px', opacity:0}, 500);

}

function closeNotification(notificationWindow) {
    notificationWindow.animate({top: '61px', opacity:0}, 500);
}
```

Basically I am trying to nest several divs and then append them to the body.

My closeNotification() function is expecting the main div with the class of "notification".  I can't use IDs because there may be more than one notification on the page at any given time.

```
<body>
    <div class="notification">
        <div class="notificationHeader">
            <div class="notificationCloser">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="notificationMessage">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have tried to use the following two methods in the notificationCloser's click code:

```
closeNotification($(this).parent().parent());
```

and

```
closeNotification($(this).parents().eq(1));
```

Oddly enough these don't seem to work but the following will hide the body:

```
closeNotification($(this).parent().parent().parent());
```

and

```
closeNotification($(this).parents().eq(2));
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: You know there's a jQuery method to add classes? [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer: use `.closest('.notification')` instead of `.parent()`.

But I'd like to suggest you a different approach. Using a template will make this much easier to reason about and clean up your code.

One simple way to make them is to wrap them in a script tag (with an unknown type, so it's ignored)

```
<body>
    <script type="text/template" id="notification-template">
        <div class="notification">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="close"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="message"></div>
        </div>
    </script>
</body>
```

(that works in all browsers, but if you're not comfortable with it you can just throw the `div.notification` element in the page with `display:none` and clone it)

And then we create a constructor function for notification objects:

```
function Notification(title, message){
    // create new DOM element based on the template
    var el = this.el = $(Notification.template);
    el.find('.header').text(title);
    el.find('.message').text(message);
    // close event handler, make sure `this` inside
    // the 'hide' function points to this Notification object
    el.find('.close').click($.proxy(this.hide, this));
}

// save the template code here once
Notification.template = $('#notification-template').text();

// methods
Notification.prototype = {
    show: function(){
        this.el.appendTo(document.body);
    },
    hide: function(){
        this.el.remove();
    }
};
```

Which can be used like this:

```
var bacon_warning = new Notification("Out of bacon", "You've ran out of bacon");
bacon_warning.show();
```

Comment: Thank you Ricardo however I now think the issue is caused by my animate

Comment: @user1462511 with this solution you'd just need a `setTimeout($.proxy(this.hide, this), 10000)` :)

Comment: I appreciate it but I am also going for HTML5 compliance.  I can't have script tags in the body.  This code is going to a .js file and included in the head.

Comment: It appears that the delay(15000) was the root of the problem.  I changed the animate line to :

 newNotification.animate({left: '10px', opacity:1}, 400);

All is good now.  In the future I will consider your approach where HTML5 compliance is not a requirement.

Comment: @user1462511 I'm not sure I follow - script tags in the body are perfectly valid in HTML5. You can also put the HTML directly on the body without the script tag, or even load it via XHR.